# How to get latest result of two different row id laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Hi i am trying to get the lates result of assessment 1 and latest result of assessment 2 order  by date.
eg.

```
     |id| name | assessment| date      |Course_code
     | 1|jon   |1          |2014-01-01 |1
     | 2|jon   |1          |2014-01-05 |1
     | 3|jon   |1          |2014-01-01 |2
     | 4|jon   |2          |2014-01-01 |1
     | 5|jon   |2          |2014-01-11 |2
     | 6|jon   |2          |2014-01-14 |1
     | 7|jon   |2          |2014-01-01 |1
     | 8|jon   |1          |2014-01-11 |1
```

here i want to get the latest assessment 2 and latest assessment 1 in single query building.
I am using laravel 4 here what i am doing.

```
DB::table('result')->where('username','jon')->where('course_code','1')->where('assignment_no',1)->orderBy('date','Desc')->limit(1)->get();
```

i hd done for assessment 1  and assessment 2 separately can i get the result for both on one single query building?

Comment: I don't know how to write in laravel but if you can use `FIND_IN_SET` please use ...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `whereIn()`, like so:

```
DB::table('result')
    ->where('username','jon')
    ->where('course_code','1')
    ->whereIn('assignment_no', [1, 2]) // you simply supply an array of values
    ->orderBy('date','Desc')
    ->limit(1)
    ->get();
```

Of course, unless you change the limit as well you're still only going to get one row.

I'm assuming that "assessment" is a typo since you have "assignment_no" in your code.